# flutter http packages show return null from Api, while in postman data is returned successfully

Tags: flutter, api, dart, postman, flutter-http

I have a connection with API, and it is working with no problem in postman: like this:
[image]

but I have a problem with flutter:
this is the code :

```
Future<List<AnswerData>> searchAnswers({required String search}) async {
    final response = await post(
    Uri.parse("$_url/search"),
    headers:  <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': "application/json",
      'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
      'Accept' : '*/*',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{"search" : "oop"})
    );
    print("status code${response.statusCode}");
    final answers = answerFromJson(response.body);
    print("msg error ${answers.data}");
    return answers.data;
  }
```

the returned status code is

```
 (200)
```

but return null, and show me this message:

```
I/flutter (10607): status code 200
I/flutter (10607): msg error : type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

and this is the model:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final answer = answerFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Answer answerFromJson(String str) => Answer.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String answerToJson(Answer data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Answer {
  Answer({
    required this.data,
    required this.links,
  });

  List<AnswerData> data;
  Links links;


  factory Answer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Answer(
    data:  List<AnswerData>.from(json["data"].map((x) => AnswerData.fromJson(x))),
    links:  Links.fromJson(json["links"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": data == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "links": links == null ? null : links.toJson(),
  };
}

class AnswerData {
  AnswerData({
    required this.title,
    required this.text,
    required this.link,
    required this.course,
  });

  String title;
  String text;
  String link;
  String course;

  factory AnswerData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AnswerData(
    title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
    text: json["text"] == null ? null : json["text"],
    link: json["link"] == null ? null : json["link"],
    course: json["course"] == null ? null : json["course"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "title": title == null ? null : title,
    "text": text == null ? null : text,
    "link": link == null ? null : link,
    "course": course == null ? null : course,
  };
}

class Links {
  Links({
    required this.first,
    required this.last,
    this.prev,
    this.next,
  });

  String first;
  String last;
  dynamic prev;
  dynamic next;

  factory Links.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Links(
    first: json["first"] == null ? null : json["first"],
    last: json["last"] == null ? null : json["last"],
    prev: json["prev"],
    next: json["next"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "first": first == null ? null : first,
    "last": last == null ? null : last,
    "prev": prev,
    "next": next,
  };
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `response`?

Comment: what do you mean by response typ?

Comment: Can you share the code of the `answerFromJson` function?

Comment: `final response = await post(`

Comment: I mean `String`, `int`, `double` or other types

Comment: i have added the model

Comment: not sure, but its only accept (Response) type

Comment: Can you print `str` and `json.decode(str)` in the `answerFromJson` function and tell me the result?

Comment: what is the str? where is it?

Comment: In the `answerFromJson` function

Comment: `Answer answerFromJson(String str) => Answer.fromJson(json.decode(str));`

Comment: it is not a problem, because this function is working in the same project:
  Future<List<AnswerData>> getAnswers({int cid = 1}) async {
    final response = await get(Uri.parse("$_url/$cid"));
    final answers = answerFromJson(response.body);
    return answers.data;
  }

Comment: Can you print `json.decode(str)` in the `answerFromJson` function and tell me the result? Because I think `json.decode(str)` might not be `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: now show me same error but return all data:
status code 200
I/flutter (10607): {data: [{title: OOP in Dart, text: object-oriented programming in dart., link: https://www.javatpoint.com/dart-object-oriented-concepts#:~:text=Dart%20is%20an%20object%2Doriented,are%20the%20real%2Dlife%20entities., course: Mobile Programming}, {title: Loop in PHP, text: for, foreach, while and do-while, link: https://youtu.be/LDQLziFLCAQ, course: Web Programming}]}
I/flutter (10607): msg error : type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: i changed to this:
Answer answerFromJson(String str) {
  print(json.decode(str));
  return Answer.fromJson(json.decode(str));
}

Comment: I think I know why

Comment: Because there is only `data` field in `json.decode(str)`. You write in your code to return null if any field is null. So you get this error.

Comment: yes, the problem because return null, as you have said, in the links, because I don't have links in search API, so just make it answer and I will accept @MyCar

Comment: I added the answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is only `data` field in `json.decode(str)`. You write to return null in your code if any field is null.